# How to play a soundless video and add a audio file at the same time?

Tags: command-line, audio, video, vlc-media-player, mp3

I have a folder with a MP3 audio file and an video file. Both named the same.

- Example.mp3
- Example.mp4

I want to play the video and add the sound.
Both files should stay the same and I do not want any new file with both in it.

Is there a way to get it done with the command line?

Comment: Just a start for others who want to help: Theoretically [VLC can do this via its GUI](http://www.netmediablog.com/how-to-play-video-with-different-audio-track-on-vlc). Next step would be to find the [correct command line syntax](http://www.videolan.org/doc/vlc-user-guide/en/ch04.html)

Comment: OK i did manage to find the Command line Syntax its:  % vlc audiofile --input-slave videofile

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer. You could and should also accept your own answer

Answer (score 4):

> How to play a soundless video and add a audio file at the same time?
>   I want to play the video and add the sound.

With the (experimental) `--input-slave` swtich.

> Is there a way to get it done with the command line?

If your video has no audio tracks, then you can simply use something like the following:

```
vlc example.mp4 --input-slave=example.mp3
```

If your video does have an audio track, then VLC will use that by default, so you have to specify the alternate track as so:

```
vlc exmaple.mp4 --input-slave=example.mp3 --audio-track=1
```

If your video has two audio tracks, then you would use `--audio-track=2` and so on (the first track is `0`, so the number you use for the external audio is equal to the number audio tracks in the video).

Also, you can (currently) only specify a single external audio track, so this will not work:

```
vlc example.mp4 --input-slave=example.mp3 --input-slave=example2.mp3
```

In this case, VLC only uses the last one specified.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted the same thing it seems. I have an app launcher I wrote in powershell, and of the things I have it doing is to create a random 8-track playlist from my music library and it slaves a random visualization video over the top in fullscreen mode.

Looks something like this: vlc.ps1

```
#cache variables
$videopath = "C:\path\to\your\mp4\videos"
$musicpath = "C:\path\to\your\music"
$numtracks = 8
$slave = @()
$slavecount =0
$rand = 0
$track = ""
$i=0

#Grab a random video
Get-Childitem -Path $videopath -Include *.mp4, *.avi, *.mkv -Recurse |
    Foreach {
        # Flip those slashes around
        $slave += $_.Fullname  -replace "\\","/"
    }
   $slavecount = $slave.Count

# Build a random 8-track
Get-Childitem -Path $musicpath -Include *.mp3, *.flac -Recurse |
    Get-Random -Count $numtracks |
    Foreach {
        #Choose a random video from the array of videos
        # This only used if they fix VLC to allow multiple slaves
        $rand = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum $slavecount

        # Add the double quotes just how vlc likes it
        $track = """" + $_.Fullname + """"

        if ($i -lt 1) {
            #start vlc, queue your first track and slave the random visualization
            vlc --started-from-file --play-and-stop $track --input-slave=file:///$slave[$rand] --fullscreen   
        } else {
            #now enqueue the remaining tracks
            #if multiple slaves are eventually supported this whole if statement can be removed
            vlc --started-from-file --playlist-enqueue $track
        }
        $i++

    }
```

Comment: Note: input slave is still pretty fussy imo. I left the loop in hopes that in the future, you will be able tp slave more than one file.

Comment: Note: input slave is slaved to the track not the queue. So your video should be short and sweet with a graceful start-end loop as it can be jarring when the video abruptly resets every track. I muxed a bunch of these together in various orders and it seems to do the trick of randomizing the visualizations http://www.dreamscene.org/gallery.php

Comment: Currently using these: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oM_Ibhqx35s